# Flutter: Set global variable using OK button on AlertDialog in StatefulBuilder

Tags: flutter, dialog, state, bloc

How to set global variable using OK button on AlertDialog in StatefulBuilder?

> `String stringMain = "My String";`
>
> ```
> Future<String?> dialogChangeMainContent(BuildContext context) {
>     return showDialog<String>(
>         context: context,
>         builder: (BuildContext context) {
>           return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
>             return AlertDialog(
>               title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
>               content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
>               actions: <Widget>[
>                 TextButton(
>                   onPressed: () {
>                     Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
>                     setState(() {
>                       // setState2();
>                       stringMain = "New String";
>                     });
>                   },
>                   child: const Text('OK'),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             );
>           });
>         });
>   }
> ```

I changed StatefulWidget from StatelessWidget, but nothing changes. What I know is the problem is because the button is in the StatefulBuilder. If using BLoC etc, it's too wasteful for only small applications.

Comment: after button clicked, you want change text to `New String`?

Comment: Where do you use <stringMain>? setState in StatefulBuilder only rebuilds the widgets inside it.

Comment: you can use ValueNotifier if you're only updating one object. check here for details https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b

Comment: shouldn't it be quick just sending the `New String` through `Navigation.pop`?

Comment: My goal is to change the String in the Text Widget by refreshing the page from the AlertDialog in the StatefulBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem, redrawing (refreshing) the Text (or other widget) in a Stateless Widget from an AlertDialog in a StatefulBuilder. By creating a **setState with a different name**, for example *setStateTarget*.
Without having to rebuild the entire page, or without state management like BLoC. My code:

> `String stringMain = "My String";`
>
> ```
> @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Column(
>       // ....
>       children: [
>         StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, setStateTarget) {
>           return Column(children: [
>             Text(stringMain), //  <--- target
>             TextButton(
>                 onPressed: () => dialogChangeMainContent(context, setStateTarget),
>                 child: const Text('Show Dialog'))
>           ]);
>         })
>       ],
>     );
>   }
>
>   Future<String?> dialogChangeMainContent(BuildContext context, StateSetter setStateTarget) {
>     return showDialog<String>(
>                   context: context,
>                   builder: (BuildContext context) {
>                     return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
>                       return AlertDialog(
>                         title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
>                         content: const Text('AlertDialog description'),
>                         actions: <Widget>[
>                           TextButton(
>                             onPressed: () {
>                               Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
>                               setStateTarget(() {
>                                 // setState2();
>                                 stringMain = "New String";
>                               });
>                             },
>                             child: const Text('OK'),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       );
>                     });
>                   });
>   }
> ```